# Size of largest sub-dictionary in python

Tags: python, pyyaml

I'm using Python with YAML configuration files. I have a YAML structure like this:

```
---
structure:
    -
        some: keys
        subsection:
            sub1: val1
            sub2: val2
    -
        some: keys2
        subsection:
            sub1: val21
            sub2: val22
            sub3: val23
            sub4: val24
```

The size of the "subsection" isn't fixed and depends on the entry.
I'm loading the configuration with PyYAML into my python script as a dictionary.
How can I do a fast check, how large the largest "subsection" is? So in this case, how can I find out that the largest subsection is four entries long? Is there a smart way without iterating it?

Thank you

Edit:
Here is the final dictionary in python:

```
data = yaml.load(...)
pprint(data)
{'name': 'value',
 'structure': [{'some': 'keys',
                'subsection': {'sub1': 'val1', 'sub2': 'val2'}},
               {'some': 'keys2',
                'precursor': {'sub1': 'val21',
                              'sub2': 'val22',
                              'sub3': 'val23',
                              'sub4': 'val24'}}
               ]}
```

Comment: How the dictionary looks like ?

Comment: data["structure"][{"some": "keys", "subsection" : { ... }}, {"some": "keys2", "subsection": {...}}]

Comment: It is still not clear, attach the sample dictionary in your question

Comment: I attached it to the question.

Comment: @ZdaR Why did you need the dictionary to make things more clear, `yaml.load()` will **uniquely** give you that from the given YAML source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your text in a file `input.xml`:

```
from ruamel.yaml import load

def get_longest(d, max_length=0):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        try:
            l = len(d['subsection'])
            if l > max_length:
                max_length = l
        except:
            pass  # no key "subsection"
        for val in d.values():
            max_length = get_longest(val, max_length)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for item in d:
            max_length = get_longest(item, max_length)
    return max_length

data = load(open('input.yml'))
```

will print you `4`. Of course you can optimize if you know all 'subsection' keys are at a certain depth. The above does not expect them to be at a certain place or level in the sequence/mapping hierarchy.

I have use my enhanced version of PyYAML ([ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml)), but for this purpose this should work the same for the older PyYAML.

```
print get_longest(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with built-ins [len](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len), [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) and a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
top = {
    "somekey":"somevalue",
    "sub1":
        {"subsub1":1,"subsub2":2},
    "sub2":
        {"subsub1":1,"subsub2":2,"subsub3":3}
}
print max(len(item) for key,item in top.items() if isinstance(item,dict))
#3
```

You should check the type of the items, because otherwise your top-level keys will also return values, but are not actually subsections.